# Difference between 'int' and 'int?'

Tags: c#, int

What is the difference between 'int' and 'int?'.  For example:

```
public int? GoalPR { get; set; }
public int AnchorPR { get; set; }
```

Comment: `int?` is a `nullable int`, which allows the value to be null.

Comment: The difference between `int` and `int?` is exactly the same as the difference between `int` and [`Nullable<int>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

Comment: @gunr2171 apologies. I tried searching for the answer.

Comment: not one person mentioned that `int?` is merely a short-hand for `Nullable<int>` o_O

Comment: @ByteBlast - uhm... yes one person did.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The  `int?` is a [nullable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/1t3y8s4s.aspx) type, so the type that can be also `null`.

The main reason of introduction of this kind of types for *value types*, is fluent support for 
*DataBase* systems, where value: can be, can be absent and can be `null`.

There are actually 3 states.

So your code that interacts with the data received and sent to DB smoothly handles that kind of situations having possibility for its own *value types* assume `null` value too.

Comment: Ah, ok that makes a lot more sense. Thank you.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [documentation for `Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx).

`int?` is just syntactic sugar for `Nullable<int>`

Answer (score 1):

`int?` can be `null`.

`int` can't.

That's (pretty much) the only difference.

Comment: That's hardly the only difference - they are different sizes and reading/writing int values is atomic, while they aren't for nullable ints.

Comment: @Lee For your first one: we're not using pointers. Second one: Sure is, unless you're using the value again, which is what most people do.

Comment: I don't see what pointers have to do with anything, and for the second point, reading/writing nullable ints is not atomic, so multiple threads updating an `int?` field could see torn reads and writes. See [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047280/is-int-thread-safe) for example.

Comment: @lee Why else would you need the size? Also, I know. However, when you're using ints most changes are something like `x = someOperations + x` and so on. And if you aren't using Interlocked there then you have a problem.

Answer (score 1):

`int?` is nullable, `int` is not..